# iOS interactive notification all actions not visible

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

I have an Interactive notification with four actions.

The actions are created as follows :

```
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *markAsReadAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
[markAsReadAction setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
[markAsReadAction setTitle:@"Mark As Read"];
[markAsReadAction setIdentifier:@"MarkAsReadIdentifier"];
[markAsReadAction setDestructive:NO];
[markAsReadAction setAuthenticationRequired:NO];
```

Created the other three actions i.e moveToTrashAction, replyAction and spamAction in the same way.

And then created the category and registered it as follows :

```
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *mailOptionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
[mailOptionCategory setIdentifier:@"MailOptionCategoryIdentifier"];
[mailOptionCategory setActions:@[markAsReadAction, moveToTrashAction, replyAction, spamAction]forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:MailOptionCategory, nil];
UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];

if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector (registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

Everything is fine when the notification is presented as alert.

[image]

But if the notification is presented as banner or viewed in notification center. Only the first two actions (Mark as Read and Move To Trash) are visible. The rest two actions (Reply and Spam) are not visible.

[image]

[image]

Regarding the Issues, am I doing something wrong or is it the default iOS behavior ?

Can I show all 4 button and while viewing the notification in notification center or presenting the notification in banner view ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referred in the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/NotificationCenter.html) document from apple:

> In addition to a default action that users can take by tapping a banner, you can also define two actions that are revealed when users swipe the banner.

and

> A notification alert is a standard alert view that appears onscreen and requires user interaction to dismiss. You supply the notification message and either a default action or up to four specific actions that are revealed when users tap the Options button.

So you are limited to those numbers, which makes sense, because stuffing four actions in one row will make it hard for the user to tap the correct one, and making it on four separate rows like alert view will take up too much space.